# How can i get the content of the edit box which created in win32?

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I created an edit box with the method in win32,which like this:

```
HWND hwnd=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"),
    NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_PASSWORD,
    0, 0, 200, 20, m_hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

it works well,but,the question is:how can i get the words that inputed in the window,some advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the edit window the [`WM_GETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. You'll need to allocate a string buffer to store the text in. You can find out the required length by sending [`WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The alternative approach, perhaps slightly simpler, is to use the [`GetWindowText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetWindowTextLength()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

For a window in the same process as the caller, there's no real difference between the two approaches.